# Errors in creating a list of (covariance) matrices using lapply in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply, covariance

I have this formula, which creates a large list of 251 elements:

```
lapply(2:nrow(mat), function(y) cov(mat[1:y,]))
```

`mat` has `dim()`:

```
[1] 252  80
```

But I want it to start from 1, i.e. `1:nrow(mat)` such that I get 252 elements similar to `nrow(mat)`. However changing `2:nrow(mat)` to `1:nrow(mat)` produces this error message:

```
lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(y) cov(mat[1:y,]))

Error in cov(mat[1:y, ]) : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

Comment: With second approach, first iteration will have only one vector: `cov(mat[1:1,])`. Can you run `cov()` on one vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you experiment with a small matrix you can see what is going on more easily:

```
mat=matrix(1:12, 3,4)

lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(y) cov(mat[1:y,]))

Error in cov(mat[1:y, ]) : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

So you are getting the `cov` of `mat[1:1,]`:

```
> mat[1:1,]
[1]  1  4  7 10
```

which suddenly isn't a matrix anymore! Which is what the error was telling you ("supply ... matrix-like 'x'"). This is because R drops dimensions when you subset a single row or column. Adjust this behaviour with `drop=FALSE`:

```
> mat[1:1,,drop=FALSE]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
```

The column-wise covariance isn't very meaningful at this point anyway:

```
> cov(mat[1:1,, drop=FALSE])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

but it at least exists...